# Prototype: select the first of two childs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype, functional-testing

I'm implementing a functional test in Ruby on Rails. I need to make an `assert_select` on a web page, which has a `content` div, which was two `<ul>`lists. I need to check the number of `<li>` items in the first list. And I can't add any class or id to any of the `<ul>` list.
So my selector would look like this:

```
assert_select 'content ul<something_here_to_specify_the_first_one> li', <number_of_li_elements
```

However, I can't find the way to do that 'select the first one of the ul elements'. I've taken a look at http://content.labnotes.org/assert_select/assert_select.html but haven't been able to figure out which one is the right for me.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select the first ul element, do:

```
content ul:first-child ...
```

Comment: What would you use to select the nth child? i.e. second one